# Unique polarization on a very general curve with Mumford-Tate

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, hodge-structure

I try to understand why a very general curve (smooth, projective over $\mathbb{C}$) has an unique polarization up to scalar on the $H^1(X,\mathbb{Q})$.

I was advised to look at the maximality of the Mumford-Tate group, but I am struggling with this strategy.

So here are the main points I have tried to use / to prove.

**First Step**

If I fix a polarized effective hodge structure $(V,q)$, let $CSp(q)=\\{f\in End(V) \ / \ \exists n\in\mathbb{Q}, q\circ f =n q \\}$. As we know that $End_{Hdg}(V)= End_{\mathbb{Q}}(V)^{MT(V)}$, where the first one is for morphisms of Hodge structure, I would like to do something similar for polarized morphisms :

$End_{HdgPol}(V)= End_{\mathbb{Q}}(V)^{CSp(q)}$

Is it true ?

**Second step**

One I am here I think that $MT(V)\subset CSp(q)$ with equality in the very general case.

**Last step**

With this I can conclude in the very general case that $End_{Hdg}(V)= End_{HdgPol}(V)$ so I have an unique polarization.

Do you think this path is true, and if it is, do you have any clue / references for my questions ?

At the beginning I thought it could be general for any Hodge structures, but it seems to be specific to the weight $1$ case. So any explanation comming from abelian variety would be welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: Was this problem given to you? In any case, here is a hint: think about the invariants of $(V\otimes V)^*$ under $MT(V)$, because a polarization lives there.

Comment: @DonuArapura in fact I have a more basic solution, but I was suggested by an advisor to look at an explanation with Mumford-Tate group. I think I have solve my second step by the minimal property of this group, and the fact that a polarized structure is a special kind of morphism from $S^1$. So I guess your hint is for the fact that there is an equality in the general case ?